# cross account access for decrypt object with default aws/S3 KMS key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-kms

In my account A, i have S3 buckets where objects are encrypted default AWS managed key aws/s3.

I want to read these objects from account B lambda . But as in account A the objects are encrypted with AWS managed key aws/s3,I cannot modify the KMS key policy here.

I tried to create a role in account A which has all KMS and S3 permission with trust the role in account B.Then from account B i am assuming this role in A. But still getting

`Access denied error in GetObject`

What can i do here to read objects in from Account A.Please guide.

Role in Account A

```
statement
{
   Action: kms:*
   Resource : "*"
   Effect: allow
}
{
  Action: S3:*
   Resource : 
      arn:aws:s3:::my-s3
      arn:aws:s3:::my-s3/*
   Effect: allow
}
```

Comment: can you show the role?

Comment: @Marcin Added the role. Kindly ignore syntax errors

Comment: Does the key policy allow that new role?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`aws/s3` is an [AWS managed key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html#aws-managed-cmk). As the [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-denied-error-s3/) explain, you can't use them for cross-account access.

> Because AWS managed KMS key policies can't be updated, **cross-account permissions also can't be granted** for those key policies. Additionally, objects that are encrypted using an AWS managed KMS key **can't be accessed by other AWS accounts**.

You have to use [customer managed keys (CMK)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html#customer-cmk) for cross-account access.